Conjugate Prior for Student T distribution with known degrees of freedom
Somebody asked a question about a conjugate prior distribution for Student-t distribution with unknown degrees of freedom. It was answered that there are no conjugate prior distribution in that case.
However, in my task I know this parameter, but the mean and the scale of Student-t distribution are not given. And I want to use a conjugate prior distribution to approximate the mean and the scale.
So what is the conjugate prior distribution for Student-t distribution in case when the number of degrees of freedom is known?

And indeed there is no natural conjugate for the parameters of a Student distribution since as already pointed out in the link the distribution is not from the exponential family.
That's being said, I think your question is not hopeless, and few clarifications should be provided in this context.
My first question is: Why do you need a conjugate prior ?. For developing a Gibbs sampler ? in a specific context such as variational Bayes ?
If you do not have any specific reason to have a conjugate prior, standard estimation procedures implemented in many softwares (NUTS), do not require conjugacy and are pretty efficient in many problems.
However, if conjugacy is mandatory for your research question, I often recommend to rewrite your prior through a hierarchical representation using full conjugacy priors. For Student distribution you can check section 4.1 of this paper: DOI:10.1214/11-BA631. It presents some interesting strategies in the context of variational Bayes for such scenarios.
I can elaborate on specific aspects if you precise your question.

I have a multi-armed bandit task. I want to use the Thompson sampling for the best speed of convergence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_sampling). Therefore I need the conjugate prior.
The most popular distribution for the levers to choose is the normal distribution. However, the "levers" in the real life are likely more to have student-t distribution with some degrees of freedom. So, I wanted to create a Thompson sampling algorithm for the Student-t distribution.

Following your comment, rewriting the student-t distribution through a hierarchical representation as pointed out in the paper should be an interesting avenue to explore. If the degrees of freedom are known, you can omit the prior over it.
